# Placing id/option value from dropdown selection into variable PHP, MySQL HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a dropdown list that is filled with some values from a MySQL table.
The issue i'm facing is that I cannot place the ID from the selected value into a variable.

This is my code up until now:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'confidential', 'confidential');
  mysql_select_db('mydb');

  $sql = "SELECT zone_naam FROM zone";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  echo "<select name='zone_1' id='zone_1'>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['idzone'] . "'>" . $row['zone_naam'] . " </option>";

  }
  echo "</select>";
  ?>
```

I would think that I could get the value from $row['idzone'] by using the code below.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$zone_1 = $_POST['zone_1'];
$richting = $_POST['richting'];
$zone_2 = $_POST['zone_2'];
}
```

I've tried several things, but I cannot come to a solution.
If I want to do the same thing in HTML with self set data like below it always works, but whenever I want to use PHP for this purpose I seem to fail.

```
<select name="zone">
<option value="1">Zone1</option>
<option value="2">Zone2</option>
<option value="3">Zone3</option>
</select>
```

I hope you all understand what I mean and can help me to find the cause of this problem.

Best regards,

Rudibwoyyy

Comment: Actually, I didn't really get what you want to tell us. Do you maybe want to get the value of the selected entry in PHP when the form is submitted? Please elaborate.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML that your first code actually builds?  `$_POST['zone_1']` would indeed hold the value submitted from `<select name='zone_1' id='zone_1'>`

Comment: Hello Kapparina, what I mean is when i'm submitting the form I want the option value from the selection to be placed into a PHP variable

Comment: after submit use echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; and tell us what have you got.

Comment: If static html works and you can POST the data, then there is an error in the html generated by PHP.  View the page in a browser and look at the html it generates.  Edit your question to include that html if the problem isn't obvious.

Comment: Hi David, at this point there is no result. It does not store the option value into $zone_1

Comment: @Rudibwoy: So, again, what is the HTML form being generated when this problem happens?  In your browser's debugging tools, when the form is posted, what values are included in the request?

Comment: @Alice I've used your code and it says that the array is empty.

Comment: @Rudi that clearly says your fields are not inside the form. Make sure your fileds are inside form tags.... example ...
 <form> YOUR FIELDS </form>

Comment: also form method  should be post

Comment: Hello everybody, the problem was in my SQL query. Instead of SELECT * i've only selected one value in the table. This is why I couldnt fetch the Id from the row. Thanks for all your help and tips!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my code that works!! Thanks for all the tips

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  mysql_select_db('confidential');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM zone";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);


echo "<form type='submit' class='form-inline' action='' method='POST'>
<select name='zone_1' id='zone_1' class='form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-        
0'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value='".   $row['idzone'] . "'>" . $row['zone_naam'] . " 
</option>";
  }
echo "</select>";



echo "<form type=\"submit\" method=\"POST\"> ";
echo "  <select name=\"richting\" class='form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0'> ";
echo "  <option value=\"<-->\"> <-->  </option> ";
echo "  <option value=\"<--\">     <--  </option> ";
echo "  <option value=\"-->\">     -->   </option> ";
echo "</select>   ";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='zone_2' class='form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['idzone'] . "'>" . $row['zone_naam'] . "
</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
  echo "<br><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$zone_1 = $_POST['zone_1'];
$richting = $_POST['richting'];
$zone_2 = $_POST['zone_2'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rudi
Then David is correct. If you submit the HTML from your post

```
<select name="zone">
    <option value="1">Zone1</option>
    <option value="2">Zone2</option>
    <option value="3">Zone3</option>
</select>
```

you can use, according the select name "zone", the variable `$_POST['zone']`, assuming you are using `<form method="post">`, (otherwise it's `$_GET['zone']`) will contain the value (1, 2 or 3 respectively) of the selected entry.

If this doesn't work for you, check if the generated HTML Code hat the correct name.